# SQL to find which members have only null entries

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I'm racking my brain trying to work out what group by and/or distinct and `count()` formation help with this but have currently drawn a blank.

Consider the table:

```
PersonId | PlaceName
---------+----------
    1    |   NULL
    1    |   NULL
    2    |   NULL
    2    | Las Vegas
    3    | London
    4    |   NULL
    4    |   NULL
    4    |   NULL
```

I'm looking for people who haven't bothered to fill in "place names", so I want my output to look like this:

```
PersonId
--------
    1
    4
```

I'll actually be joining some other tables in to pull out the info on each "miscreant" person, but the crux of my problem is the one above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
SELECT PersonId
  FROM TheTable
 GROUP BY PersonId
 HAVING COUNT(PlaceName) = 0
```

The `COUNT()` aggregate function ignores `NULL`s, so the right result should be returned.

Comment: Ahhh, that's nice and simple. Great, it works with the example, now to hook up the joins. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
select PersonId
from MyTable
group by PersonId
having count(case when PlaceName is not null then 1 end) = 0
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99d45/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct t1.id
from test t1
LEFT JOIN
(
  select id, count(name) nm
  from test 
  where name is not null
  group by id
) x
  on t1.id = x.id
where x.nm is null
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/860d2/7)

Comment: How does this exclude entries (personid) with multiple null and one completed placeName? Sorry to be dense, just not seeing it...

Comment: @DavidW It doesn't. Nor does it include rows with only a single null entry. It just happens to work on the sample data set.

Answer (score 0):

I would offer the following:

```
select distinct a.personid 
  from tablename a
  left outer join tablename b
    on a.personid=b.personid
   and b.placename is not null
 where b.personid is null
order by personid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT PersonId
FROM MyTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM MyTable WHERE PersonId = t.PersonId AND PlaceName is not null)
```